# Programming AMO OLAP Objects

Tags: c#, ssas, mdx

I have the following Mdx code

```
Scope (
        {[Dim PNL].[PNL].&[88]}
,[Measures].members


);       
this = iif( aggregate([Dim PNL].[PNL].&[12],[Measures].currentmember)<>0, 
aggregate([Dim PNL].[PNL].&[60],[Measures].currentmember)
/(-1* aggregate([Dim PNL].[PNL].&[12],[Measures].currentmember)),null
);       
End Scope;
```

I'm trying to reate it using a MDX ADOMD command from C# code.Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the cube structure via ADOMD, but you can using AMO. However, you will have to do all the parsing of the calculation script yourself, as all you can access is one large string containing the complete calculation script.

Assuming you have an AMO Cube object named `cube`, you can access the calculation script for reading and writing via

```
cube.DefaultMdxScript.Commands[0].Text
```

After doing your changes, you should call

```
cube.Update()
```

to write the changes back to the running cube.

As you see, technically there can be several calculation scripts in a cube. But BIDS combines all of them to one on reading (at least I think it does), and on writing, BIDS writes everything to the first script again.

Comment: How can I parse the calculation script ? any idea ?

Comment: Well, you have to know what you are searching, and then use any string search method like regular expressions. If order does not matter for the part of the calculations that you want to add with your code, of course the simplest approach would be to just append it to the end of the script.